# need to display a picture gallery in rows and columns

Tags: asp.net, image

I am working on an ASP.net site and I just want to display pictures from a folder to a page on the site. I will like to pictures to be a uniform aspect ratio and with # of rows and columns.

At this point I am not sure if I want to do a database. Please forgive me if answers to this question exists already.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know alot about asp.net, but I may be able to help you choose whether to use a DB or not.

It depends on your situation.

If you're only going to need one set of images, you may as well just put them in straight away. Becuase you're not going to change them, they will just stay as they are.

If the images are going to, for instance, be uploaded by the user, a database might be a better idea. Things in databases can be accessed from anywhere in the site. It is easier to categorise, and choose images by category if they're in a database. This might depend on your DB setup, but images in a database cannot be accessed as a plain image by a visitor, whereas (unless you have some type of security/put them in a protected directory) they can if you just upload them to the server.

I would say, weigh up the options and use which one seems to be better for you.

- "*cannot be accessed as a plain image by a visitor*" As in, you can't go to a page like [this](http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/6f538965cb5de93a049ceee34aabfa30?s=128&d=identicon&r=PG)

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to use `list view control` to display images as you said and here is the way you can get started through http://www.dotnetcurry.com/ShowArticle.aspx?ID=175